# Maven cli gives syntax error but in eclipse is ok. Is java syntax correct? Really strange

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors

I'm having a very strange issue in my java application. I'm building it with maven and developing it in Eclipse IDE. This might be a bit lengthy explanation but please stick to the end of it, cause the problem is really strange and I have no clue what can be the cause of it.

Here's an example of code I'm writing:

Suppose we have a "Handler" interface. It can handle a specific object type:

```
public interface Handler<T> {
    public void handle(T obj);
}
```

Now let's say we want to have Handler chaining. We could do it like this:

```
public class HandlerChain<T> implements Handler<T> {

private Handler<? super T> h;

@Override
public void handle(T obj) {
            //h can handle T objects
    h.handle(obj);  
}

private HandlerChain(Handler<? super T> h) {
    super();
    this.h = h;
}

    //syntax sugar to start the chain
public static <T> HandlerChain<T> start(Handler<? super T> h){
    return new HandlerChain<T>(h);      
}

    //add another handler to the chain
public HandlerChain<T> next(final Handler<? super T> handler){
    return new HandlerChain<T>(new Handler<T>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(T obj) {
            h.handle(obj);
            handler.handle(obj);                
        }
    });     
}

}
```

Now let's make some handler factories for, say, String handlers:

```
 public class Handlers {
public static Handler<String> h1(){
    return new Handler<String>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(String obj) {
            // do something

        }

    };
}

public static Handler<String> h2(){
    return new Handler<String>(){

        @Override
        public void handle(String obj) {
            // do something

        }

    };
}
}
```

So finally we make a class that handles some Strings using the two handlers in a chain:

```
public class Test { 
public void doHandle(String obj){
    HandlerChain.start(Handlers.h1()).next(Handlers.h2()).handle(obj);
}
}
```

So, to me there seemed nothing wrong with this code. Eclipse IDE didn't mind either. It even ran it correctly. But when I tried to compile this code with maven from cli, I got an error:

```
Test.java:[7,50] next(Handler<? super java.lang.Object>) in HandlerChain<java.lang.Object> cannot be applied to (Handler<java.lang.String>)
```

Had anyone stumbled upon similar problems? I would really like to know if this kind of syntax is valid in java or is this some strange compiler bug due to bad setup or something? To repeat Eclipse compiles AND runs this code correctly, but maven cli cannot compile it.

Finally, here's my maven-compiler-plugin settings in pom.xml. It might be relevant to the whole issue.

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just hacked this in a freshly created Netbeans/Maven project and - guess what? - it compiles like a charm from within IDE and from commandline! Maybe post the exact versions of Maven and JDK you use (i tried Maven 3.0.5 / JDK 1.7.0_11). Or check the output from mvn -X compile for something obvious

Comment: Hmmm. I'm using Maven 3.0.4 and JDK 1.6.0_27. I'll definitely try to update maven to see if problem goes away tomorrow. As for JDK that'll have to go through higher authority :-). Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: OK, checked this with JDK 1.6 and then i get the same compilation error! So there is a difference between Java 6 and Java 7, but i'm not sure if this "bug or feature" :-)

Comment: Did you use maven compiler plugin settings posted above? If source and target were explicitly set to 1.6,   should there be a difference between jdk 6 and jdk 7?

Comment: Yes, i copied and pasted your plugin settings in my pom.xml; so the only difference was a different JDK in the path. It seem like JDK7 handles the "<? super T>" in a different way. BTW, what was your intent declaring some type parameters as "<? super T>" ? When i replace this with just "<T>" the example compiles on JDK6.

Comment: Well, Handler<T> would naturally be able to handle subtypes of T. The same goes for HandlerChain<T>. So, without <? super T> in next() method, I would not be able to chain Handler<X> with Handler<T> where X extends T. But you're right about start() :-) it should not have <? super T>! That's the solution to the problem,thanks again :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Had anyone stumbled upon similar problems?

Yes, and also when doing weird and unusual (probably incorrect) stuffs with generic types.

The problem was that the eclipse compiler don't report a compilation error on those strange construct while the standard `javac` from Sun JDK complains about type erasure. (it was with JDK 1.6). (If I remember well: eclipse report a only a warning)

My solution was to setup maven to use eclipse compiler. The other (better) option was to fix the code, but since it was a quite complex task and since I didn't have any issue at runtime I choose the "quick and dirty" first option.

Here is how to setup the compiler:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
            <source>${compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${compiler.target}</target>
            <encoding>${source.encoding}</encoding>
            <fork>false</fork>
            <compilerId>jdt</compilerId>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
                    <version>0.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```